# Relacionamento um pra muitos e muitos pra um Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo essas classes desse diagrama, porém estou na dúvida como declarar os relacionamentos [Um pra muitos, e muitos pra um]

Esse é o diagrama:[image: Diagrama de classes]

por exemplo Produto tem uma Categoria, e uma Categoria tem Vários Produtos:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Preço de Compra")]
    public double PrecoCompra { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Preço de Venda")]
    public double PrecoVenda { get; set; }

    public double Desconto { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }
    public string Garantia { get; set; }
    public string Fabricante { get; set; }

}
```

Categoria

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Desconto { get; set; }
}
```

Como eu faço pra declara-las para o EF entender esses relacionamentos?

Nesse diagrama, para declarar a classe pessoa que tem endereço eu fiz:

```
    public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    ...
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Está correto essa declaração?

Grato

Comment: estou tentando aprender com isso: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx se eu conseguir entender tudo, posto aqui dps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [EntityConfig](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/) para fazer esse mapeamento de uma forma elegante e pratica.

É importante o uso do [Virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542879/2740371) em seus relacionamentos, isso permite que o Entity Framework crie um proxy em torno da propriedade virtual para que a propriedade possa suportar o carregamento preguiçoso e o rastreamento de mudanças mais eficiente.

Deixei comentado algumas descrições.

```
// virtual ICollection<Products> Products cria uma lista de produtos na categoria ... 
// Virtual permite que o Entity Framework crie um proxy em torno da propriedade virtual 
// para que a propriedade possa suportar //o carregamento preguiçoso e o rastreamento de mudanças mais eficiente. 
public partial class Categories
{
    public Categories()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Products>();
    }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
}

// virtual Categories Categories { get; set; } Cria um objeto categoria para cada produto.
public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; } 

    public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }
}

// Configuração usando o code first 
public class CategoriesConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Categories>
{
    public CategoriesConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.CategoryID);
        Property(p => p.CategoryName).HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(p => p.Description).HasColumnType("ntext").HasMaxLength(400).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.Picture).HasColumnType("image").IsOptional();

        ToTable("Categories");

        // HasMany declara que categorias tem varios produtos 
        // WithOptional diz que o produto pode ter ou não uma categoria ..
        HasMany(p => p.Products)
            .WithOptional(p => p.Categories);
    }
}
```

Comment: então nesse exemplo, `WithOptional` recebe uma função que espera um objeto do tipo `Products` e retorna um do tipo `Categories` é isso ?

Comment: a parte de ter um `public int CategoriesId {get;set;}` dentro de `Products` pra ser usada coomo FK não precisa ?  (desculpe as perguntas, estou tentando entender isso...rs....nunca trabalhei com EF)

Comment: Não precisar, você já tem a navegação para categorias que tem seu id. // WithOptional diz que o produto pode ter ou não uma categoria .. No caso pode receber um valor NULL

Comment: Esse código esta disponível no git https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/Projetos/tree/master/Projeto_Modelo

Comment: Retornou um no meu mapeamento:

MLoja.Models.Context.Produto_Categoria: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Produto_Categoria_Target' in relationship 'Produto_Categoria'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Comment: Meu onmodelBuilder:

modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.Categoria)
                .WithMany(p => p.Produtos).HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoriaId);

Comment: remover o .HasOptional(p => p.Categoria)

Comment: Deu erro aqui pra compilar.

modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()
                .WithMany(p => p.Produtos).HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoriaId);

Comment: Sim... sua relação é M-M entre produtos? Não seria .WithMany(p => p.Produtos) ... .Entity<**Categoria**>() .WithMany(p => p.Produtos)

Comment: minha relação é um pra muitos.

Comment: você esta tentando fazer uma relação de Produto para Produto altera o modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()  para modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>()

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo de mapeamento 1xN:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CurrentGradeId { get; set; }
    public Grade CurrentGrade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configures one-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasRequired<Grade>(s => s.CurrentGrade)
            .WithMany(g => g.Students)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.CurrentGradeId);          }
    }
}
```

Referência: [aqui](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)